# Can dynamic components be used in a form as form fields and validation still be handled by the parent component?

Tags: angular

Just trying to learn the use of dynamic components.  For context (and suggestions of better solutions if appropriate):  The application receives questions (question title + possible options which can include multi-select, true/false, likert scale, open-ended, etc.).

My idea is to use dynamic components to display the part that can change from question to question:

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
      <app-question-response-configuration [question]="question"></app-question-response-configuration>
      <input type="text" ngModel name="test">
      <hr>
      <button
        disabled="{{ form.invalid ? 'disabled' : ''}}"
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit</button>
    </form>
```

An example of html found in a dynamic component:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let choice of question.choices">
      <input
        ngModel
        required
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        value="{{ choice.id }}"
        name="questionChoices[]"
        id="choice-{{ choice.id }}"
      >
      <label class="form-check-label" for="choice-{{ choice.id }}">
        {{ choice.label }}
      </label>
    </div>
```

As far as displaying, the component factory does what I want it to do for different question types.  However, functionality such as `form.valid` on the `button` does not work - I'm assuming this is because the parent component doesn't know anything about what's happening on the child yet.

At this point I'm really unsure where to go - do I need to emit from the child and handle validation manually?  I'm not even sure of the right question to be asking.

Comment: You should look into Angular's `ControlValueAccessor`. You'll implement an interface that will allow Angular to interact with `<app-question-response-configuration>` as if it's no different from an `<input>`.

Comment: Interesting, I'm investigating now.  As `app-question-response-configuration` is really just a placeholder that will be replaced with a dynamic component, is it possible I need to implement the interface on the base class (`QuestionResponseOptionComponent`) as that is what my dynamic components extend?

Comment: I believe you'll need to implement it on `app-question-response-configuration` because that's the top-level component present in your form. That component will then need to manage value getting/setting with the component it creates dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your component a `Form` control like this

```
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-response-configuration',
  templateUrl: 'your-template-html' 
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => QuestionResponseConfigurationComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class QuestionResponseConfigurationComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() question = "";

  // Function to call when the input is touched (when a star is clicked).
  onTouched = () => {};

  // Get the value of the form control
  get value(): number {
    return this.question;
  }

  // Set the value of the form control
  writeValue(value: number): void {
    this.value = value;
    this.onChange(this.value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (rating: number) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // Allows Angular to disable the input.
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    // some logic
  }

}
```

Some good explanation of the functions [here](https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf):

> onChange → the callback function to register on UI change
>
> onTouch → the callback function to register on element touch
>   set value(val: any) → sets the value used by the ngModel of the element
>
> writeValue(value: any) → This will will write the value to the view if the the value changes occur on the model programmatically
>
> registerOnChange(fn: any) → When the value in the UI is changed, this method will invoke a callback function
>
> registerOnTouch(fn: any) → When the element is touched, this method will get called